# odoo15 kanban view doesn't support one2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

`lading_adapter_ids` is a one2many field in the module.

Here is code, and all `t-out` show a blank.

```xml
 <t t-foreach="record.lading_adapter_ids.raw_value" t-as="o">
                                        <t t-out="o.name" />
                                         <t t-if="i % 2 != 0" >
                                            <hr />
                                        </t>
                                        <t t-set="i" t-value="1"/>
                                        <i class="fa fa-location-arrow" title="This is the district" />
                                        <t t-out="o.district" />
                                        <br />
                                        <i class="fa fa-building" title="This is company name" />
                                          <t t-out="o.display_name" />
                                        <br />
                                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" title="This is the address" />
                                          <t t-out="o.eng_address" />
                                         <br />

                                     </t>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use those fields.

The [function](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/b309d3a99f8ff4a43a21c4772c344ed3250e319f/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/kanban/kanban_record.js#L618) that builds the object containing the formatted record data used in the template, sets the `raw_value` to a list of ids in the case of `one2many` and `many2many` fields

From kanban view documentation:

> Each field has two attributes value and raw_value, the former is formatted
> according to current user parameters, the latter is the direct value from a [read()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.read)
> (except for date and datetime fields that are formatted according to user’s locale)

By default, fields are replaced by their formatted value, unless the `widget` attribute is specified, so you can define a new widget, like `many2many_tags` to change the behavior of the One2many field in kanban views.

If you look in the [FieldMany2ManyTags](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/b309d3a99f8ff4a43a21c4772c344ed3250e319f/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/relational_fields.js#L2548) class you will see a special attribute `fieldsToFetch` used to retrieve the fields used in the rendering context.

To define a new widget, `kanban_address` based on the value of a One2many field:

- You need to extend the `AbstractWidget`
- Set the fields to retrieve
- Define a new template
- Alter the `_render` function to render the newly created template.
- And finally, use the new widget in the field tag in the kanban view.

***Example:***

*1- Kanban Widget*

```
/** @odoo-module **/
import field_registry from 'web.field_registry';
import AbstractField from 'web.AbstractField'
import  { qweb as QWeb, _t } from 'web.core';

var FieldKanbanAddress = AbstractField.extend({
    custom_template: "kanban_address",
    supportedFieldTypes: ['one2many', 'many2many'],
    fieldsToFetch: {
        name: {type: 'char'},
        district: {type: 'char'},
        display_name: {type: 'char'},
        eng_address: {type: 'char'},
    },

    _render: function () {
        var elements = this.value ? _.pluck(this.value.data, 'data') : [];
        this.$el.html(QWeb.render(this.custom_template, {elements: elements}));
    },
});

field_registry.add('kanban.kanban_address', FieldKanbanAddress);
```

*2- Custom template*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="kanban_address">
        <t t-foreach="elements" t-as="o">
            
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

*3- `widget` attribute*

```
<field name="move_raw_ids" widget="kanban_address"/>
```

*4- Specify JS and XML files in the [manifest](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/assets.html#assets)*

```
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        
        '{MODULE_NAME}/static/src/js/kanban_address.js',
    ],
    'web.assets_qweb': [
        '{MODULE_NAME}/static/src/xml/kanban_address.xml',
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple alternative, you could use a computed field (type:html) + not stored in the database : loading_adapter_dispfields with a
dependency on : loading_adapter_ids

```py
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    loading_adapter_dispfields = fields.Html("Display loading_adapter_ids fields", compute="_compute_loading_adapter_dispfields", store=False)

    @api.depends("loading_adapter_ids")
    def _compute_loading_adapter_dispfields(self):
        for record in self:
            record['loading_adapter_dispfields'] =  '<i class="fa fa-location-arrow" title="This is the district" />'+record.loading_adapter_ids.district+'<br/><i class="fa fa-building" title="This is company name" />'+record.loading_adapter_ids.display_name
```

and in the inherited xml view :

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='name']">
    <field name="loading_adapter_dispfields" widget="html" />
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON in a text field.

In Python, create a computed field:

```
one2many_text = fields.Text(compute='_compute_one2many_text')
```

In compute function, fill the field with a JSON:

```
import json
def _compute_one2many_text(self):
    for rec in self:
        data = []
        for i in rec.one2many_field:
            data.append({
                'id': i.id,
                'name': i.name
            })

        rec.one2many_text = json.dumps(data)
```

In the template tags of your view:

```
<t t-foreach="JSON.parse(record.one2many_text)" t-as="line">
    <p><t t-esc="line.name"/></p>
</t>
```